# How to read a random word from .txt using Java JFrame

Tags: java, random, jframe

My program needs to read a random word from a `.txt` file that contains lot of words (in different lines).

I am able to choose a random word from an array, but I have not found how to read a random word from `.txt` file.

```
public class GuessForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    String[] FindWord1 = {"hello", "hey", "well", "story", "fight","punch"};
    int idx = new Random().nextInt(FindWord1.length);
    String FindWord = (FindWord1[idx]);
    int wordL = FindWord.length();
    // ...
```

I have tried the following, but it does not work:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.io.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class GuessForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    String filename = "H:\\lol.txt";
    File file = new File (filename);
    Scanner input = new Scanner new FileReader(file));
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        String FindWord1 = input.next();
    }
    int idx = new Random().nextInt(FindWord1.length);
    String FindWord = (FindWord1[idx]);
    int wordL = FindWord.length();
}
```

Comment: That code won't even compile, and shows that you're making wild random guesses, a coding process that never works. Stop. Delete that file, and start over, and on this second go-around, divide the problem into small steps, and then try to solve each single step **one at a time**. Don't combine until each smaller step is solved. Then if you're still stuck, you can at least ask a more reasonable and answerable question.

Comment: What does JFrame have to do with reading a file? You might want to go through the [Java I/O tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way if you're reading many words would be to read the whole file into memory and store it in an array.

If you are only checking once, then it is possible that you could save some time by only reading through once and not building any data structure.  Note that it uses a lot of calls to a `Random` object.

```
public String randomWord(String file)
{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    int i = 1;
    Random r = new Random();
    String line, out;
    while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        if(r.nextDouble() < (1.0 / i++))
            out = line;
    return out;
}
```

You will need to add in some try/catch or other exception handling, but something like that should work

This method of obtaining a random element is useful mainly for Iterators/LinkedLists/files